# What does fflush do before fork operation?

Tags: c, process, fflush

I wanted to know how many times does `printf` print "PROCESS" if the snippet below is given:

```
int main()
{
    printf("PROCESS");
    fflush();
    fork();
    fork();
}
```

Please explain the logic both with and without `fflush();`.

Comment: As written, it gives a compiler error as fflush requires an argument...

Comment: invoke undefined behavior, since you're not passing a required parameter to [`int fflush( FILE *stream );`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush). Apparently you didn't include `stdio.h` or this wouldn't even *compile* (and still won't in C99-strict or above).

Comment: You might want to [read about `fflush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) and what it does, and more importantly what arguments it takes.

Comment: If you omit the `fflush()`, you see 4 strings `PROCESS` on the output, possibly interleaved.  If you fix and include the `fflush()`, you get just one `PROCESS` on the output.  If you included a newline at the end of the printing (as you normally should), then you'd normally see just one line even without the `fflush()`, unless you redirected standard output to a file or a pipe (when you'd see 4 again).

Comment: BTW, the code is many times wrong: ; missing `#include <stdio.h>` & `#include<unistd.h>`; `fflush` needs an argument (so call `fflush(NULL);` ...), and result of `fork` should *always* be *kept* and *tested* (for the three cases `==0`, `>0`, `<0`....)

Comment: @jonathan leffler, thank you .that was the answer i wanted to know and got the reason too. And i know i missed the #includes and fflush syntax was not right, i just posted the snippet of the code .

Answer (score 2):

It writes the data stored in the stdio buffer out to the console. Thus entering into the process with a clear buffer - ie. not getting "PROCESS" printed out multiple times

PS: Assuming you meant `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: I can only hope you meant 'fflush(stdout)'.  fflush(stdin) is specifically stated as being undefined behaviour.

Comment: Freudian slip on my part